# Create a list when clicked on an imagebutton

Tags: java, android

hey guys this is arjun narahari
i m experiencing a problem while creating a list when clicked on an imagebutton
need some assistance from u guys
posting the code down here

This is my homepage.java where my imagebutton is at the topright

```
package com.nb.list;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class HomePage extends Activity {

ImageButton stats;
ListView lv;
String[] info = { "Mary(Wife)", "Alex(child-1)", "Steven(child-2)",
        "Robert(Father)", "Diana(Mother)" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.homepage);


    stats = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgstts);

    stats.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    info);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    });
}
```

}

my list.xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

i m getting an error when clicked on the imagebutton , the app stops
and in eclipse 
it shows

```
10-23 17:23:30.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1296): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-23 17:23:30.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1296): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-23 17:23:30.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at com.nb.vaultHR.HomePage$5.onClick(HomePage.java:88)
10-23 17:23:30.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
10-23 17:23:30.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
10-23 17:23:30.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
10-23 17:23:30.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-23 17:23:30.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-23 17:23:30.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-23 17:23:30.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 17:23:30.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-23 17:23:30.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-23 17:23:30.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-23 17:23:30.914: E/AndroidRuntime(1296):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-23 17:23:33.303: I/Process(1296): Sending signal. PID: 1296 SIG: 9
```

can somebody guide me as where i m going wrong and what do i have to do to make it work
thanking you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logcat is saying this :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.nb.vaultHR.HomePage$5.onClick(HomePage.java:88)
```

I suppose this line is the following :

```
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

If I read your entire code, I can found the declaration of `ListView lv`, but a value is never assigned. So `lv`stays null forever.

You have to add something like : `lv = findViewById(android.R.id.list);` in your `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your listview is null. This should do it:

```
stats.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                info);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
});
```

Comment: ok , i m sorry to say bt i m getting the same null pointer exception error , i corrected my mistake pointed out by u guys , bt unfortunately i cant get the listview , the app stops